# Does django-private-chat save chat history?

Tags: django, messaging

I'm working on a django project in which I need to implement one-to-one chat/message for users. I am thinking more like LinkedIn messaging. Here is an ideal situation.

1. messages show up in a chat box
2. a user can send message when the other user is offline
3. messages are somehow saved. so when a user opens up the message box,
   all prior messages show up.
4. a user can delete message history
5. notification about unread messages (in the app, not by email)

I did some search and found [django-private-chat](https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat) that seems can do 1, 2, but not the other ones.

**Question 1:** django-private-chat seems not saving chat history. Am I right? If so, is there any way I can save the chat history?

**Question 2:** Is there any other packages that I should take a look?

Thanks.